# cakephp 2.3 format time input hours minutes seconds

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to format my input without any success. I need to save mp3 to my table with the duration of each audio file. For that, I would like to have an input that allows me to choose hours:minutes:seconds. The field for the duration in my table is TIME, I don't need a dateTime for that I guess.

So here is what I've done that doesn't work:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('duration', array('type' => 'time', 'label' => 'Durée piste', 'dateFormat' => 'H:i:s')); ?>
```

Does anyone knows how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an open PR to allow seconds. So far, you have to write your own method or use a group of inputs to simulate. See: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3943-feature-request-seconds-field-input-for-datetimetimetimestamp-formhelper

Comment: Thanks Mark, I checked it out unfortunately I didn't understand what I read :). I'm not a php expert :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are not a php expert then you can go with simple code given below.

**Note: Post is my Model name.So Replace it with yours.**

Add function in your controller

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Post->create();

            $hours   = $this->data['Post']['hours'];
            $minutes = $this->data['Post']['minutes'];
            $seconds = $this->data['Post']['seconds'];

        $this->request->data['Post']['duration']=$hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;


            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in add.ctp file

```
$hours=array();
for($i=0;$i<13;$i++){
  $hours[$i]=$i;
}

$ms=array();
for($i=0;$i<60;$i++){
  $ms[$i]=$i;
}

echo $this->Form->input('hours',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $hours));
echo $this->Form->input('minutes',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $ms));
echo $this->Form->input('seconds',array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $ms));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ketan patel! Everything is working fine, I even added some 0 when the number is single to look like this: 01:07:33

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your old arrays with these new arrays.

```
$hours=array();

for($a=0; $a < 2; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b < 10; $b++){
        if ($a.$b == 13) {
            break;    
        }
        $hours[$a.$b]=$a.$b;

    }
}

$ms=array();

for($a=0; $a < 6; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b < 10; $b++){
        $ms[$a.$b]=$a.$b;
    }
}
```